# Finding the union of RDDs which may not exist

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to get the union of a few RDDs. The RDDs are being read in via SparkContext.textFile, but some may not exist on the file system.

```
val rdd1 = Try(Repository.fetch(data1Path))
val rdd2 = Try(Repository.fetch(data2Path))
val rdd3 = Try(Repository.fetch(data3Path))
val rdd4 = Try(Repository.fetch(data4Path))

val all = Seq(rdd1, rdd2, rdd3, rdd4)
val union = sc.union(all.map {case Success(r) => r})
val results = union.filter(some-filter-logic).collect
```

However due to lazy evaluation, all those `Try` statements evaluate to `Success` regardless of whether the files are present or not, and I end up with a `FileNotFoundException` upon evaluation when `collect` is called.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run a loop to check whether the file exists and in the same loop you can create the RDDs and get a union.
OR 
you can use wholeTextFiles API to read all the files present in one directory as key,value pair.

```
val rdd=sc.wholeTextFiles(path, minPartitions)
```

If any file will be empty also, it will not not create any issue.